# How to escape the \s character in AMPScript RegExMatch?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I would like to use the `\s` (any white space character) to find matching words using AMPScript RegExMatch function. When using the following regex the `\s` is not matching a white space character and `@RESPONSE` is always `NO`.

```
VAR @result
VAR @RESPONSE

SET @result = RegExMatch("YES ", "^(?:YES|Y|YO|YEP)\s", 0, "IgnoreCase", "Multiline")
IF Length(@result) > 0 THEN
  SET @RESPONSE="YES"
ELSE
  SET @RESPONSE="NO"
ENDIF
```

If I use a regex like `^YES` without the `\s` then the regex works.

I have tested regex in .net as per [RegExMatch function description](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/#RegExMatch) with `\s` and it works as expected.

Can anyone suggest how to fix so that regex uses the `\s` as an any white space character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the following, I was able to get the response you were after, I think.

In the third example, I included a `?` at the end of the regex to qualify the `\s` as occurring zero or more times.

```
%%[
var @result
var @response
var @str
set @str = "YES"
set @strWS = "YES "

/* match string with whitespace at the end */
SET @result1 = RegExMatch(@str, "^(?:YES|Y|YO|YEP)\s", 0, "IgnoreCase", "Multiline")
set @response1 = iif(length(@result1) > 0, "YES", "NO")

/* match string with whitespace at the end */
SET @result2 = RegExMatch(@strWS, "^(?:YES|Y|YO|YEP)\s", 0, "IgnoreCase", "Multiline")
set @response2 = iif(length(@result2) > 0, "YES", "NO")

/* match string with zero or more whitespace characters at the end */
SET @result3 = RegExMatch(@str, "^(?:YES|Y|YO|YEP)\s?", 0, "IgnoreCase", "Multiline")
set @response3 = iif(length(@result3) > 0, "YES", "NO")

]%%
str: |%%=v(@str)=%%|
<br>result1: %%=v(@result1)=%%
<br>response1: %%=v(@response1)=%%
<br><br>strWS: |%%=v(@strWS)=%%|
<br>result2: %%=v(@result2)=%%
<br>response2: %%=v(@response2)=%%
<br><br>str: |%%=v(@str)=%%|
<br>result3: %%=v(@result3)=%%
<br>response3: %%=v(@response3)=%%
```

**Output**

```
str: |YES| 
result1: 
response1: NO 

strWS: |YES | 
result2: YES 
response2: YES 

str: |YES| 
result3: YES 
response3: YES
```